# OSStatus NSOSStatusErrorDomain

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

I received the following error when I get the property using

```
AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate,&size,
                                      &myAudioDescription.mSampleRate)
```

Error Produced by above statement is

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557673 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560557673.)"
```

Now, here what does 560557673 mean and where can I find its explanation?

Documentation only provides NSOSStatusErrorDomain as one of the errors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That code means the property data size was not correct.

`OSStatus` is a type commonly used for error codes in OS X and iOS. If the magnitude of the code is less than 1 million, then the code is probably listed in MacErrors.h in the CarbonCore framework. Otherwise, it is probably a four-character code listed in the same header as the function which returned it. You can find the header of a function by command-clicking it in Xcode. The codes will most likely be listed near the top, grouped together. To convert the number to a code, use the Calculator app in Developer view to convert it to hexadecimal and convert each byte to a character.

Comment: could you explain the conversion of 560557673 to an understandable string.

Comment: @andyPaul If you convert that to hexadecimal, it takes four bytes, each of which is an ASCII character. 560557673 is 0x21696E69, which is the string '!ini'.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Absolutely brilliant!